# relative File path in php

Tags: php, apache, windows-7, xampp

Short version:
How do relative paths work in php?

Long version:
I have a local web site (**http://test.com**) and `E:\test\`  is its document root. This is my Directory tree:

1. E:\test\001.php
2. E:\test\exit.php
3. E:\test\death.txt
4. E:\test\mysql\first.php
5. E:\test\mysql\death.txt
6. E:\test\mysql\exit.php

And Contents of files:

E:\test\001.php

```
<?php

include('mysql/first.php');

?>
```

E:\test\exit.php

```
<?php
die('What?');
?>
```

E:\test\death.txt

```
Bonjour
```

E:\test\mysql\first.php

```
<?php
echo file_get_contents('death.txt');
include('exit.php');
?>
```

E:\test\mysql\death.txt

```
Hello there
```

E:\test\mysql\exit.php

```
<?php
die('DONE');
?>
```

If I browse `http://test.com/001.php`  and `E:\test\exit.php` and `E:\test\death.txt` exist, I get this:

```
BonjourWhat?
```

And If they don't exist:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(death.txt) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in E:\test\mysql\first.php on line 2
DONE
```

How do relative paths workin php? I thought it should give me warning for both files or show proper output !

I'm testing this code on Win7 x64 with XAMPP, php 5.3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how the documentation on php.net describes the PHP `include` search mechanism:

1. First, it will look in the include_path:
   http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path.
2. Then it will try to load the file in the calling script's own directory if it could not find anything in the include_path. (in our
   case, the root directory)
3. Finally, if everything else failed, it will then try to find the file in the current directory.

When I ran your scripts, my include path was set to `.:` by default (the current directory and nothing else), so when I try to load `death.txt` and `exit.php` from `mysql/first.php` it should search in `./` folder which is the current directory. But... **It does not**. The current directory should be `mysql/` but it's not pointing there... So what's happening here?

PHP is quite special with that... Let's rollback to the first statement we made. What is PHP interpreting in our `include path` when it uses the `.` is actually a path resolution again! So, looking at our path, we have `.` which can't be interpreted (`./.` again?) to anything using our include_path. Then, PHP has to go to the second path resolution (2) which is the root directory of our script. (have you got an headache yet? Because I do)

Using `get_include_path()` and `realpath()` you can observe this:

```
Included path: '.:'
Including mysql/first.php: /Users/Kouno/Development/SandBox/test-php/mysql/first.php
This is what `realpath` returns for './': /Users/Kouno/Development/SandBox/test-php
Getting content of death.txt: /Users/Kouno/Development/SandBox/test-php/death.txt
Bonjour
Including exit.php: /Users/Kouno/Development/SandBox/test-php/exit.php
What?
```

Then, why does it specifically fail to load `mysql/death.txt` but still find `mysql/exit.php`, once you remove `death.txt` and `exit.php` from your root directory? It should find both of them, right?

Well, it's because `get_file_content` has a second parameter which ignores `include_path` by default.

If you set the second parameter:

```
echo file_get_contents('death.txt', FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);
```

Then you would get the expected result.

```
Included path: '.:'
Including mysql/first.php: /Users/Kouno/Development/SandBox/test-php/mysql/first.php
Getting content of death.txt: (no path returned)
Hello there
Including exit.php: (no path returned)
DONE
```

The funny thing is that `get_file_content()` will start using the same mechanism as `include` (and this is not documented properly on php.net). And `realpath()` doesn't even implement this mechanism at all (which explains why I have a `no path returned` showing up).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

first.php find file death.txt in E:\test\mysql.
You can use:

```
echo file_get_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'death.txt');
```

or:

```
echo file_get_contents('..' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'death.txt');
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm **NOT** looking for a solution to `file_get_contents` problem, I want to know how relative paths work !